# Shell Script to Detect if the IP Address Is Googlebot

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

I'm trying to do a bulk reverse DNS the IP's which I got from CloudFront Logs with help of below shell script, which I need to differentiate whether it's suspicious or genuine Googlebot IP. But I'm not getting the output. Not sure where I am going wrong. Is there any other option to do bulk reverse DNS?

```
#!/bin/sh
file="googlebots"
while read -r line
do
    hostName=`host $line | cut -d" " -f 5`
    domainName=`echo $hostName | cut -d"." -f2,3`
    #echo $domainName
    #echo "$hostName"
    hostIp=`host $hostName | cut -d" " -f 4`
    #echo "$hostIp"
    if [ $line == $hostIp ] && [ $domainName == "googlebot.com" ]
    then
        echo "Googlebot: $hostIp -> $hostName"
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Comment: "But I'm not getting the output." Can you explain what do you mean by that? Any errors? Also do you have example of the input file ?

Comment: There is no way we can answer this without knowing a bit of what `"$file"` looks like